# Улучшить описание визитки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, настройки-профиля, визитка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

На странице настроек визитки описание:

> (обратите внимание, что **визитка будет отображаться** только для тех
>   сообществ, где у вас есть более 200 баллов репутации, информация в
>   визитке обновляется один раз в 24–36 часов).

Но в оригинале:

> (please note that only **sites** where you have more than 200 reputation
>   **will appear**, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.)

Визитка так и так будет отображаться, а вот сайты на ней будут отображаться, только если на них есть хотя бы 200 репы. Нужно бы поправить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/8907

Предложил:

> (обратите внимание, что отображены будут только сайты тех сообществ,
>   где у вас есть не менее **200** баллов репутации, и что информация в
>   визитке обновляется один раз в 24–36 часов).

Comment: Утвердил-дил-дил!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, рррр.. а пообсуждать?

Comment: @Qwertiy ... :P

Comment: @Qwertiy нет такой метки! :) Можем вернуться к этому вопросу через некоторое время и посмотреть по ответам.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю такой перевод:

> (обратите внимание, что в визитке отображаются только сообщества, где вы набрали не менее 200 баллов, а информация обновляется каждые 24-36 часов)

Comment: Читая "а информация обновляется" так и хочется поставить вики-примечание [где?] после слова "информация". Это минус, должно быть сразу понятно "где" - и этим вариант Suvitruf лучше. С другой стороны "вы набрали не менее" лучше, чем вариант "у вас есть не менее"